# can't create functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to add some udfs to MySQL server, and I've got .dll file in the mysql/lib/plugin folder.

I opened a MySQL client and it reports some strange errors.

```
mysql> create function ipv6_ntop returns string soname 'libmysql-udf-ipv6.dll';
ERROR 1125 (HY000):  Function 'inet6_ntop' already exists
```

and then i tried to drop this function:

```
mysql> drop function inet6_ntop;
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION (UDF) inet6_ntop does not exist
```

Comment: Why would you try to drop a function if you didn't create it successfully on the first place?

Comment: If the function wasn't created (first message), then obviously you cannot drop it (second message).

Comment: ‘cause i don't know whether this function already exists

Answer (score 0):

Try checking http://kmaiti.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-install-tcpwrapper-on-linux.html .
It looks like you have to import your 'ipv6_ntop' into library.

http://www.justskins.com/forums/issues-creating-function-140539.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

And again - you can't drop something if you haven't created it first.

Comment: how to import libmysql-udf-ipv6.dll to mysql, i add it to the lib/plugin folder

Answer (score 0):

`mysql> drop function 'inet6_ntop';`   /*WITH QUOTES*/